# Migrate Spring Web Application (web.xml) to Spring Boot Executable Jar

Tags: spring-boot

Okay I've done a lot of googling and I can't seem to find a clear answer. Let's keep it as simple as possible. I have a web.xml file

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>A</listener-class>
</listener>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath*:springcontexts/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:wsspringcontexts/*.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring_mvc_contexts/*.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I think I know how to migrate this to Spring Boot ...

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
@ImportResource("classpath*:springcontexts/*.xml")
public class Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Somewhere in a sub-package...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMVCConfiguration
{
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean mvc()
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.setConfigLocation("classpath*:spring_mvc_contexts/*.xml");
    // the dispatcher servlet should automatically add the root context
    // as a parent to the dispatcher servlet's applicationContext
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/spring/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("DispatcherServlet");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }
}
```

...and we do the above again for the other Servlet

My first problem is how to add the listener "A" to Spring Boot and ensure it runs before the root application is refreshed? Some beans that get configured require some static fields to be setup (legacy code), and this setup is done in listener "A". This works fine when deployed as a standard war using the above web.xml

In addition does the above Spring Boot setup look correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your legacy initialisation in a postConstruct method on a bean ?

Failing that you can add a listener that implements

`ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`

and overrides

`public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event)`

Does your Spring Boot setup look OK ? Difficult to tell, though I'd let Spring Boot autoconfigure things like the dispatcher servlet for you and get rid of any XML config if at all possible.

Comment: I need to reproduce the logic as is given in the web.xml above. The listener that runs legacy code needs the ServletContext and runs before the Spring Listener runs (which bootstraps Spring). I must be able to reproduce the web.xml as given above in Spring Boot?